# Fly wheel design in MSC ADAMS

Tags: flywheels

I am trying to model a crank rocker mechanism with flywheel. The flywheel is attached on the crank arm join so the crank and flywheel will be rotating with same speed. My aim is to reduce the the torque fluctuation of four bar mechanism with flywheel. And I need the crank arm to rotate in constant RPM. I want to know how to model the system?. As I keep the RPM same the angular acceleration is zero, hence I can't see any change in torque variation with change the mass or inertia of the flywheel.

Comment: The torque fluctuation is solely based on the input.  What you want to minimize is the change in angular velocity.

Comment: Ok so you beed to be a bit careful with your modeling. If you force the shaft to rotate at a certain speed then there are no dynamics! instead you need to impart forces, or moments then there are dynamics but speed wont be constant untill you reach a steady state.